# backbone event trigger

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I want to trigger a custom event from my backbone view class then where I Instantiate the view I want to listen for the event.

Simplified Example:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
     render:function(){
         this.trigger('customEvent', "working");
     }
});
```

// Separate js file with jquery ready method.

```
$(function() {
    var myView = new view();
    myView.bind('customEvent', this.customEventHandler);

    function customEventHandler() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have a question? you've only stated what you want to do, with no issues, no questions, or anything that can be answered

Comment: Note that `myView.bind('customEvent', this.customEventHandler);` needs to be `myView.bind('customEvent', this.customEventHandler, this);` - you have to provide the context when passing an instance method as a handler.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - you only have to pass the context when you need to set a specific context. in your example, "this" would refer to the global object as the event binding is happening outside of the View

Comment: Derick sorry if its not clear what I'm trying to do with the above code. But my setup is giving me an error saying callback[0] is undefined. If there is something else I can supply that might help you understand my question please let me know. I'm trying to trigger a custome event from the view class and listen for it in the js file where the view class is instantiated.

Comment: you are missing `var` before `customEventHandler`

Comment: nrabinowitz thanks for the reply. Its still not working when I use the extra context of this at the end of the bind method. I still get an error callback[0] is undefined
 callback[0].apply(callback[1] || this, args);

Comment: @DerickBailey - well, it's unclear what context his code is running in (whether it's global or within a function) - the bit at the end is clearly within some other piece of code, given the comma. It's true that you don't need to pass in `this` if `this.customEventHandler` is static.

Comment: nrabinowitz my view instantiation is within a jquery ready function I updated my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the error you're getting is "callback[0] is undefined", then your problem is in the event binding. Where you have:

```
myView.bind('customEvent', this.customEventHandler);
```

What does `this` refer to, and does it have a `customEventHandler` method? If this is all happening in the global scope, you can just pass in a plain function, no `this` required:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
     render:function(){
      _this.trigger('customEvent', "working");
     }
});

// define your callback
function customEventHandler() {
    // do stuff
}

myView = new view();
myView.bind('customEvent', customEventHandler);
```

This will work even with a `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Hi nrabinowitz I updated my code to show the context of where view is created and where the bind method is added. IF I leave out the this I get a different error onTimeSelected is not defined
myView.bind('customEvent', customEventHandler, this);

Comment: @Chapsterj - you still aren't providing full code here. `customEventHandler:function()` has to be within an object literal somewhere, or the `:` would be a syntax error. What object does it belong to?

Comment: ITs part of the jquery ready object just like in my updated example in my first post. it could be written like function customEventHandler(){} if that makes it easier to understand but its still giving an error.

Comment: Ok updated my script to show your function style but still getting the same error.

Comment: nrabinowitz when I changed to your function notation and removed the this.customEventHandler it worked. Whats starnge is my method notation before didn't throw an error. like you mentioned above. Its working now thanks